# If left to right and right to left - both associativity of operator are present in a statement then What will be considered?

Tags: c, associativity

```
int i=-1;
int a=65;
int b=a*i + ++i;
```

What is the value of b?
Here associativity of =,+ is left to right and associativity of *,prefix increment (++) is right to left.

So What order of evaluation should I consider for  int b=a*i + ++i;

left to right? 
right to left? 
Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not think about assosiativity. Think about order of evaluation and unfortunately it is undefined in this case.
In the expression

```
int b=a*i + ++i;
```

you are modifying `i` as well as using it in the same expression which invokes **undefined behavior**.

C99 states that:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, **the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored**.

Further I would suggest you to read [c-faq: Q 3.8](http://www.c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html).

Comment: A statement doesn't _invoke_ undefined behavior. A statement _has_ undefined behavior. "Undefined behavior" is not a function that gets invoked.

Comment: yes, _cause_ is also fine. Sorry for nitpicking, but I'd seen people say _invokes undefined behavior_ so many times...

Comment: @Shahbaz [invoke](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invoke) has a plain English meaning which makes perfect sense in that context.

Comment: You _did_ use that term didn't you? ;) Never mind though, I only said it to prevent confusion. With _invokes undefined behavior_ it sounds like (to a noob) that the compiler or whoever deliberately goes and invokes something called undefined behavior when it sees code like that.

Comment: @Shahbaz the standards committee uses such language as well, for example this [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1719.htm) so I would consider this a term of the field and explain it is needed to anyone who does not understand.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; Thanks for clearing up the things.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, interesting. I'm not a native speaker, so perhaps I'm not clear on all usages of invoke (I thought it just means _call upon_). Nevertheless I had just asked [a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/158556/14369) on english.SE.

Comment: @Shahbaz; I am waiting for the answers.

Comment: @Shahbaz: "Invokes undefined behaviour" is a (even 'the') conventional way to describe what happens when a program does something that the standard specifies as leading to 'undefined behaviour'.  I use the term; I am going to continue using the term.  It is more convenient than most of the circumlocutions.

Answer (score 2):

here you should consider the operator precedence. here the expression is solved based on precedence of the operator so at a time only one associativity is applied.
The associativity comes into picture `when the operator has same precedence` and in that case associativity will be same.
In your question `b=a*i + ++i`  `i` used twice results in `undefined behavoiur`.

otherwise it would be evaluated as,
++ followed by * then + `operation according to precedence`.
if this was followed the the answer would be,

```
b=a*i + ++i
b=65*i + 0
b=65*0 + 0
b=0 + 0
b=0
```

but the compiler can use the stored value of i instead of using value after ++i,

```
b=a*i + ++i
b=a*-1 + 0
b=-65 + 0
b=-65
```

this results in undefined behaviour since b can be 0 or -65. and also you can see that `associativity doesn't create problem while evaluating` since `operators with same precedence will have same associativity` and evaluation is ordered by precedence first and within that ordered by associativity.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things associativity and precedence .

First check precedence and then associativity.

In you expression int b=a*i + ++i;

++has higher precedence than + and * so first ++ would be evaluated.
After that + and *, * has higher precedence so * is evluated.
In the last + is evaluated.

It's also the case as haccks suggested, you should not modify and use the  value in the same expression.(not a good practice)

Comment: So, according to your answer, if the expression would be `b = a*i + ++c;` then `++c` get evaluated first and then `a*i` and the result of both get added?

Comment: yes .... If you put the expression like that b=a*i + (++c) otherwise it would take the ++ with i..... I means to say only one thing.... first it would take ++(increment) before + and *(binary operator). And also one more thing... unary operator always has higher precedence than binary operator.

Comment: Then this is alarming! You need to revise your basics.

Comment: it depends on associativity and also on compiler for gcc